# assign a key value list to an array in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have a list that is a key value paired list.  Something like the following

```
key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3
```

I would like to map this to an array or a dictionary.

Currently, my code looks like this

```
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list]} {incr i} {
  if {[expr {fmod($i,2)}] == 0} {
    set key [lindex $list $i]
  } else {
    set v_array(${key}) [lindex $list $i]
  }
}
```

In perl, I know this can be assigned into a key value dictionary in one pass.  Is there such simpler method in Tcl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an array in one line (I'm using one line to define the list):

```
% set list [list key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3]
key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3
% array set v_array $list
```

And if you want to check the contents, you can use parray (Tcl 8.5 and later):

```
% parray v_array
v_array(key1) = value1
v_array(key2) = value2
v_array(key3) = value3
```

And the documentation for the other array commands can be found [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm) with examples for each.

---

If you somehow cannot avoid a loop, then using [`foreach`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm) would be easier (be sure the list has an even number of elements):

```
foreach {a b} $list {
  set v_array($a) $b
}
```

(Here `foreach` is taking the elements in `$list` two at a time and assign them to a and b)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dict`  command for creating/manipulating dictionaries in `Tcl`.

```
% set mydict [dict create key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3]
key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3
% dict get $mydict
key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3
% dict get $mydict key3
value3
% dict get $mydict key1
value1
%
```

Even without the `dict create` command, you can straightway fetch/access the keys and values even from a list as long as it is in key-value form. i.e. even number of elements.

For example,

```
% set mylist {key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3}
key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3
% dict get $mylist key2
value2
```

As you can notice, I have not used `dict create` command here , but still able to access the dictionary items.

**Reference :** [dict](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution:

```
set mylist {key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3}
array set arr $mylist
```

Thats it.

Now, do a parray to check.

file: t3

```
#
set list [list key1 value1 key2 value2 key3 value3]
array set arr $list
parray arr
#

Execute the file: tclsh t3
arr(key1) = value1
arr(key2) = value2
arr(key3) = value3
```